# hide an element after leaving the page - razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, hide, actionlink

how can I show an ActionLink, which is located in a section in the layout, when I enter a specific page, which is part of the body, and then hide the ActionLink when i leave the page. I been thinking on using cookies, but I dont know how to assing the flag value to hide the element after leaving the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use next way

```
@{ 
     var controller = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
     var action = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
}
  <a class="@((controller == "News" && action== "Index") ? "show" : "hide")" href="#">
My link
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the data somewhere and wrap the rendering of the link in an IF statement to see if it needs to display or not.

You can use a Session variable, if you have session turned on.  The next time they come back to the site, the link will show up because a new Session will be initiated.

Cookies, as you suggested would work also.